# Correct way of referring to the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that spans the $x$-axis?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

I'm used to thinking of $\mathbb{R}^1$ as (basically) the $x$-axis in one dimension. Similarly, I think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the $xy$-plane in two dimensions (*i.e.* in contrast to the plane $z = 0$ in Cartesian space / $\mathbb{R}^3$).

This aligns with the fact that $\mathbb{R}^1 \not\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^1, \, \mathbb{R}^2  \not\subset \mathbb{R}^3$; however, I'm left wondering: **is there a conventional way of referring to the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$?**

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

---

Edit:

**Basically I'm wondering if there is any convention for a shorthand to refer to $\text{Span}\left\{ \, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \,  \right\}$ and $\text{Span}\left\{ \, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \, \right\}$ (as well as analogous subspaces in higher dimensions)?**

---

An example of a situation I would like to use this notation in:
a succinct way of asking if a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a basis for $\text{Span}\left\{ \,\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \,  \right\}$.

Obviously asking "is $\text{Span}\left\{ \, \vec{v}_1 \,  \right\} = \mathbb{R}^1$" would be incorrect, and "is $\text{Span}\left\{ \, \vec{v}_1 \,  \right\}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$" isn't what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Assuming that you are asking about vector subspaces (given your choice of tag), the subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ that are isomorphic  to $\mathbb R^k$ are known as the $k$-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Is there a shorthand / symbol for these?

Comment: That's the standard terminology. It's a good terminology because it is precise and descriptive. There's not much need, nor much demand, to shorten precise, descriptive, terminology which is already reasonably short terminology. But if you were writing in some context where those 20-odd characters are too many, feel free to introduce a briefer terminology: "We'll refer to a 1-dimensional subspace as a BLAH and a 2-dimensional subspace as a SNERD"; that kind of thing is also common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is thinking about "the" subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}$. There are infinitely many. You can single out the three coordinate axes as special since you are representing vectors as ordered triples, but the $x$-axis is no more special than the other two axes and does not have another common name. Even calling the $x$-axis relies on the convention that the axes are labelled $x$, $y$ and $z$. In higher dimensions that won't work.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm well aware that there is nothing special about those subspaces (i.e. that there are infinitely many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I just thought there might be a special name for these ones, the way there is a special name for the standard basis vectors... Was just looking for a clear way of discussing the difference between them with students, while keeping the distinction explicit. Thank you for the clear answer.

Comment: Just to confirm (see edit to OP): there is no standard notation for referring to the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\text{Span}\bigg\{ \, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \, \bigg\}$, other than referring to it as the span of $\hat{\imath}$? I was waiting to see if anyone else would weigh-in, but doesn't look likely, at this point. Will mark this as the correct answer as soon as you confirm.

Comment: I know of no standard notation and I probably would if there were one. You could refer to it as the $x$-axis, or the first coordinate axis, or as the span or multiples of $\hat i$ or of $e_1$, depending on previously established context.

Comment: Thank you -- so far I have been referring to it as, e.g. "the x-axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$" , so that is reassuring :D